# The UPDATE query of Mysql setting a value to a constant always...?

Tags: php, mysql

The Update customer query in this code setting `phno` to a constant 2147483647
 always instead of setting to the value submitted... i tried echoeing $phone its correct.. but its not working when im executing query....

```
<?php
    include 'database.php' ;
    $id=$_POST["customer"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $address = $_POST["address"];
    $phone = $_POST["phno"];
    $sql = "UPDATE `customer`  SET `phno`=$phone, `name`='$name',`address`='$address' WHERE actno=$id";
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
      }
    echo "successful";
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: What is the structure of your database?  More specifically, what type is `phno` and what is the format of `$phone`?

Comment: Change phno to varchar(20)

Comment: @Akhil It could be longer than 20, i.e. +1 (123) 555-0123 ext 1234

Comment: I hope it is just a common sense to increase 20 to whatever you wish to .

Comment: @Akhil You think it's common sense, but it seems like the field type is an integer, not a varchar, which also seems common sense.  Beginners will be beginners and just go with it.

Comment: I dont think we need to give that level of spoon feeding.. .. Just my view..

Comment: hmm i know its very small thing... i gave phno as integer... and $phone is text but atleast it has to change values when i change from my form...

Comment: very strange.. although i tried givin a number phno=213412 like that its no working...

Comment: and when i execute the same query from phpmyadmin.. its working...

Comment: @KrishnaKittu So have you tried doing `echo $sql;` after your `$sql` assignment to make sure it's properly formatted?  Have you entered *that* manually?  What is the size of your integer?  You probably want a varchar anyway, as referenced above.

Comment: Yes the size i gave in database for phno is no sufficient.. thanx for response @BLaZuRE :)

Comment: yeah i have switch to varchar...

Comment: Big Int worked for me instead of varchar :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `phno` as `INTEGER`, didn't you? The maximum value of `INTEGER` is 2,147,483,647, so any number larger than 2,147,483,647 is out-of-range, and will be inserted as 2,147,483,647.

Change the datatype of `phno` to `BIGINT` or `VARCHAR`.

Also, your query is vulnerable to SQL injections, see the link below for more details.

See also:

- [Integer Types in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)
- [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/130323/1935077)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to substitute $phone in the string,
but it wont work that way, either you split the string or use {}.

Comment: You're only halfway right, though I don't think you realize how.  You are allowed to use a double-quoted string with a variable inside, and PHP will interpret that variable (like `"$myVar"`.  However, for single-quoted strings, you need to use concatenation (like `'Hi ' . $myVar`).  For the part you're right about, if `$phone` is a string, then it should be in quotes for MySQL to know it's a string *if there is a space in it*.